# Xamarin.Forms StackLayout IsEnabled after selected item in ListView

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.forms

I have problem with it. I want to show more info in label in stacklayout after selected item in ListView, but i can't use x:Name of stack because in code behind xamarin cannot see my reference. I have done it like this

Code:

```
private void ChallengeList_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SelectedItem == null)
            return;
    More.IsEnabled = true;
    //ChallengeList.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

My Xaml Code:

```
<ListView x:Name="ChallengeList" SeparatorColor="#3d122c" HasUnevenRows="True"
            ItemSelected="ChallengeList_ItemSelected"  RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression ElementName=Lab, Constant=0,Factor=1,Property=Height,Type=RelativeToView}"
      RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Property=Height,Factor=0.8,Type=RelativeToParent}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  BackgroundColor="#40FFFFFF" Padding="10">
                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="#ff3f50" FontSize="17" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" IsEnabled="False" x:Name="More" >
                                    <Label Text="sdfghjkhgfdsfghjkljhgfdsadfghjkljhgfdsaSDFGHJKJHGFDSAsdfghjkhgfds" TextColor="#ff3f50" FontSize="17" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
           </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see element `More` because it is in ListView's Item Template, so it is dynamicly generated. Probably you can access `More` inside your `ViewCell` but not outside it (so in your Page / View).

Let's assume that in code behind you are setting `ItemSource` of your ChallengeList to list of your view models.
I would suggest you to add property IsEnabled to your view model, bind `IsEnabled` from StackLayout to this property and in `ChallengeList_ItemSelected` change property of your view model

Example:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _isEnabled = false;
    public bool IsEnabled 
    {
        get => _isEnabled;
        set => Set( ref _isEnabled, value);
    }
}

<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" x:Name="More" >
    ...
</StackLayout>

private void ChallengeList_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SelectedItem is MyViewModel viewModel)
    {
        viewModel.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? It's difficult to help if you don't provide any information.

Comment: Set not extist in current context but i create new object and error have disappeared. I think that IsEnabled is still true, because if i start app layout is enalbed in listview.